# Result of AND'ing / OR'ing 0 arguments?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've implemented a basic set algebra system that operates on sets of strings or "marks."  I added MultiAnd and MultiOr convenience functions that each take an array of marks and AND's / OR's them all together.

So what happens if an empty array is passed to those functions?  My intuition is that MultiAnd( {} ) should return the universe since more and more AND'd marks are restrictive (i.e. result set gets smaller as number of arguments grows), so the "limit" as number of arguments goes to 0 means the universe, right?  Similarly, I'd expect MultiOr( {} ) to return the empty set.

Related, I'm assuming that passing exactly 1 argument to either MultiAnd or MultiOr should just return everything having that mark.

Is my intuition correct or am I doing something mathematically dangerous?

---

Sample output from the following universe of fruits with possible marks "tasty", "round", "red", and "spikes!":

- Banana: {"tasty"}
- Grapefruit: {"round"}
- Granny Smith Apple: {"tasty", "round"}
- Carolina Reaper: {"red"}
- Strawberry: {"tasty", "red"}
- Pineapple: {"tasty", "spikes!"}
- Durian: {"round", "spikes!"}
- Honey Crisp Apple: {"tasty", "round", "red"}
- Cranberry: {"round", "red"}
- Lemon: { }

Proposed MultiAnd outputs:

- MultiAnd({}) -> universe (all fruits returned)
- MultiAnd({"red"}) -> { Carolina Reaper, Strawberry, Honey Crisp Apple, Cranberry }
- MultiAnd({"red", "tasty"}) -> { Strawberry, Honey Crisp Apple }
- MultiAnd({"red", "tasty", "round"}) -> { Honey Crisp Apple }

Proposed MultiOr outputs:

- MultiOr({}) -> {} (empty set)
- MultiOr({"spikes!"}) -> { Pineapple, Durian }
- MultiOr({"spikes!", "tasty"}) -> { Banana, Granny Smith Apple, Strawberry, Pineapple, Durian, Honey Crisp Apple }
- MultiOr({"spikes!", "tasty", "round"}) -> { Banana, Grapefruit, Granny Smith Apple, Strawberry, Pineapple, Durian, Honey Crisp Apple, Cranberry }

Comment: I don't understand what exactly MultiAnd and MultiOr do on nontrivial inputs, so I don't feel comfortable writing a full answer, but what you describe sounds consistent with mathematical conventions for things like [the nullary intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29#Nullary_intersection) and [the union of the empty collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Arbitrary_unions) and [the empty conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product#In_logic), etc.

Comment: After reading your links, MultiAnd and MultiOr would seem to correspond to [arbitrary / infinitary intersections / unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29#Arbitrary_unions).  (I did not previously know the correct terminology.)  But your links seem to confirm that I was on the right track.  Thanks!

Comment: I agree that it would help if you showed us what these functions do with various ordinary inputs.

Comment: Sorry,  perhaps I was trying to be too minimalist.  Added example expected output.